# Factorize $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+6)- 3x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I'm preparing for an exam and was solving a few sample questions when I got this question -
Factorize : $$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+6)- 3x^2$$ 
I don't really know where to start, but I expanded everything to get :
$$x^4 + 12x^3 + 44x^2 + 72x + 36$$
I used rational roots test and Descartes rule of signs to get guesses for the roots. I tried them all and it appears that this polynomial has no rational roots.So, what  should I do to factorize this polynomial ?

(I used wolfram alpha and got the factorization : $(x^2 + 4x + 6) (x^2 + 8x + 6)$ But can someone explain how to get there ?)

Comment: The Maple command $$ infolevel[factor] := 5: factor((x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3)*(x+6)-3*x^2)$$ produces $$(x^2+8*x+6)*(x^2+4*x+6) $$ and the explanation how this is found.

Comment: @user64494 I don't have maple but can you please share the explanation that the software gave ?

Comment: @ A Googler: See Maple worksheet exported as a PDF file [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/3962570748/factor.pdf).

Comment: Don't post PDF files as answers. Type them out so future users can still read it, even if your link dies.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A way to do it is to write $(x+2)(x+3) = x^2 + 6x + 6 - x$, $(x+1)(x+6) = x^2 + 6x + 6 + x$, so

$$
(x+2)(x+3)(x+1)(x+6) = (x^2 + 6x + 6)^2 -x^2 
$$
which gives that
$$
(x+2)(x+3)(x+1)(x+6) - 3x^2 = (x^2 + 6x + 6)^2 -4x^2 = (x^2+ 4x + 6)(x^2 +8x + 6).
$$

Comment: Wonderful ! But I'm curious to know how did you realize to split (x+2)(x+3)(x+1)(x+6) into two parts  (x+2)(x+3) and (x+1)(x+6) ? Also is this because 2*3=1*6=6 ? Does this method always work if in  {(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)} , a*b=c*d ?

Comment: Yes it was because 2*3=1*6 = 6 and that the whole expression was nearly on the form $x^2-y^2$, so this is not a very general method and does not work in general cases.

Comment: @AGoogler: Experience.  Such groupings often come up.  For example, prove that $$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)$$ is never a perfect square for any $x$.

Comment: @Eric ...unless you allow _negative_ integers for $x$.  The zero product allowed in that case is the only perfect square.

Answer (score 33):

I'm assuming that you are looking for a factorization of the polynomial
$$
f = x^4 + 12x^3 + 44x^2 + 72x + 36
$$
in $\mathbb Q[x]$.
By the Lemma of Gauss and the fact that $f$ is monic, this is the same as looking for a factorization in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Since there are no rational roots, the only remaining possibility is the factorization into two factors of degree 2. Since the polynomial is monic, the factors may be assumed to be monic.
So the putative factors have the form $x^2 + ax + b$ and $x^2 + cx + d$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$.

This leads to
$$
f = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d) = x^4 + (a + c)x^3 + (ac + b + d)x^2 + (ad + bc)x + bd.
$$
Comparing the coefficients, we get four equations
$$
a+c = 12\\
ac + b + d = 44\\
ad + bc = 72\\
bd = 36
$$
Up to swapping the two factors, the last equation has the solutions
$$
(b,d)\in\{(1,36),(-1,-36),(2,18),(-2,-18),(3,12),(-3,-12),(4,9),(-4,-9),(6,6),(-6,-6)\}.
$$
It's a bit of work, but plugging these values into the remaining three equations, you find that only for $b=d=6$ there is a solution, which is $a = 4$, $b = 8$ or $a = 8$, $b=4$. This gives you the two factors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !                                            I searched for Gauss's lemma and found a Wikipedia article . But I didn't really understood it . Can you please explain the lemma ?

Comment: @AGoogler: I applied the corollary from Grauss's lemma that a primitive polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over the integers iff it is irreducible over the rationals.

Comment: @AGoogler primitive polynomials with coefficients in `Z` are closed under multiplication. integer coefficients `<=>` all roots are in `Z`.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+6)-3x²$$
$$(x+1)(x+6)(x+3)(x+2)-3x²$$
$$(x²+6x+1x+6)(x²+3x+2x+6)-3x²$$
$$(x²+6x+6+1x)(x²+5x+6+x-x)-3x²$$
$$(x²+6x+6+1x)(x²+5x+x+6-x)-3x²$$
$$(x²+6x+6+1x)(x²+6x+6-x)-3x²$$
$$(x²+6x+6)²(+1x)(-x)-3x²$$
$$(x²+6x+6)²-x²-3x²$$
$$(x²+6x+6)²-4x²$$
$$(x²+6x+6)²-(2x)²$$
Apply $a²-b²=(a+b)(a-b)$
$$(x²+6x+6+2x)(x²+6x+6-2x)$$
$$(x²+8x+6)(x²+6x-2x+6)$$
$$(x²+8x+6)(x²+4x+6)$$
$$x(x+8+6/x)x(x+4+6/x)$$
Answer: $$x²(x+8+6/x)(x+4+6/x)$$

Answer (score 2):

$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+6)-3x^2$

$\rightarrow(x+1)(x+6)(x+2)(x+3)-3x^2$

$\rightarrow(x^2+x+6x+6)(x^2+2x+3x+6)-3x^2$

$\rightarrow(x^2+7x+6)(x^2+5x+6)-3x^2$

$\rightarrow(x^2+6+7x)(x^2+6+5x)-3x^2$

Put :- $x^2+6=y$ eq($1$) . So :-

$(y+7x)(y+5x)-3x^2$

$\rightarrow y^2+7xy+5xy+35x^2-3x^2$

$\rightarrow y^2+12xy+32x^2$

$\rightarrow y^2+4xy+8xy+32x^2$

$\rightarrow y(y+4x)+8x(y+4x)$

$\rightarrow (y+4x)(y+8x)$

Put value of $y$ from eq(1), we get :-

$\rightarrow (x^2+6+4x)(x^2+6+8x)$

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a mathjax reference to typeset math.