# Factoring $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to factor this polynomial:
$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1$$
*WolframAlpha* gives 
$$(x^2+5x+5)^2$$
How can I prove it without expanding the result?

Thanks!

Comment: First step: Check if both have the same zeros.

Comment: If you can pretend you "guessed" the factorization, notice $(x^2+5x+5)^2-1$ is a difference of squares.

Comment: Use $x^2 + 5x + 6 = (x+2)(x+3)$ and $x^2 + 5x + 4 = (x+1)(x+4)$ and Jean-Claude's tip above.

Comment: @gammatester but then you will only prove that the set of roots from one polynomial is included in the set of roots of the other. Stay to show that $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1$ has two distinct roots of multiplicity $2$...

Comment: @Winther and @ Jean-Claude Thanks!

Comment: Subtract  1 then factor the difference of squares

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463506/factorize-x1x2x3x6-3x2). You can do it like this:
$(x+2)(x+3) = x^2+5x+5+1$, $(x+1)(x+4) = x^2+5x+5-1$, so
$$
(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4) = (x^2+5x+5+1)(x^2+5x+5-1) = (x^2+5x+5)^2-1^2.
$$
This gives the answer $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1 =(x^2+5x+5)^2 $.

Comment: Wow, I like it!

Answer (score 13):

Evaluate both polynomials at $x = -1, -2, -3,$ and $-4$. They are equal at these four values, and their leading coefficients are both equal to $1$. So they are the same polynomial.

Comment: Simply beautiful!

Comment: So simple when you see it, nice!

Comment: I was just about writing the same solution. 
To clarify: 4 points fixate a polygon of degree 4.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks! What if the result was unknown?

Comment: @e-man: Ah, now that's a different question :-)

Answer (score 5):

$(x^2+5x+5)^2-1^2=(x^2+5x+4)(x^2+5x+6)=(x+1)(x+4)(x+2)(x+3)$

Comment: Your answer is a clear one! +1

Answer (score 3):

The key for this problem is observing that $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1$ is symmetric with respect to $x=-2.5$. Write it as

$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+1= \\
 \left( (x+2.5)-1.5\right)\left( (x+2.5)-0.5\right)\left((x+2.5)+0.5 \right)\left((x+2.5)+1.5 \right)+1$$

For simplicity, let us denote temporarily $x+2.5$ by $y$. Then we need to factor

$$\left( y-1.5\right)\left(y+1.5 \right)\left(y-0.5\right)\left(y+0.5 \right)+1=\left( y^2-1.5^2\right)\left(y^2-0.5^2\right)+1$$

Now, this is a quadratic in $y^2$, which can be factored by completing the square. Then replace $y=x+2.5$.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma**  $\ ad\!-\!bc = -2\,\Rightarrow\, abcd = e^2\!-1,\,\  e = ad\!+\!1 = bc\!-\!1$

**Proof** $\ $ Notice that $\ abcd = (ad)(bc) = (e\!-\!1)(e\!+\!1) = e^2\!-1\ $ **QED**

Yours is the special case $\ a,b,c,d\, =\, x\!+\!1,x\!+\!2,x\!+\!3,x\!+\!4$

**Generally**  $\ \ AB\, =\, \left(\dfrac{A+B}2\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{A-B}2\right)^2 $

The Lemma is the special case $\,\ |A\!-\!B|\, =\, 2.\ $ This identity often proves useful when one wishes to replaces multiplication by squaring(s) - just as in your problem.